# ReactJS without JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React to generate a decently huge and complicated DOM tree structure 
but I choose not to go with JSX (*just to avoid the eventual and unavoidable 
transformation from JSX to JS again*). Some portions of this DOM will be generated or visible to user based on certain (if-else) conditions. In another case, a loop might be required to generate a few HTML elements and so on.

However, I could not find any good atricles around that explain React without JSX.

Hence, **please guide and show how to use ReactJS without JSX** and using Factory, class, components and others.

There are not enough documentations on this.

Comment: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/displaying-data.html#react-without-jsx

Comment: https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/using-reactjs-without-jsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try the library we made at Uqbar:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/njsx

It's quite easy to use and provides a cleaner interface than the React out-of-the-box interface.

Comment: Thanks! Glad it helped. Please, do visit the project's Github and share any ideas/requests.

Comment: Nice, well thought out API and the terse implementation. Sadly, it looks unmaintained.

Answer (score 5):

It seems like you're aware JSX converts to JS.

So instead of writing JSX ...

```
// jsx
var data = [1,2,3];

var nodes = <ul>{data.map(function(p,i) {
  return <li><Person key={i} id={p} /></li>; 
})}</ul>;
```

Just write the JS with [React.createElement()](https://react.dev/reference/react/createElement) instead !

```
// js
var data = [1, 2, 3];

var nodes = React.createElement(
  "ul",
  null,
  data.map(function (p, i) {
    return React.createElement(
      "li",
      null,
      React.createElement(Person, { key: i, id: p })
    );
  })
);
```

Comment: Exactly, I know all these but I need more details, such as on `createClass`, `createFactory`, `Components`, etc. When and how these can be used especially in my scenarios.

Comment: Well you can either read the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html) or just paste any valid JSX into http://babeljs.io/repl and you'll see the correct output there.

Comment: Really tho, you're just making an uphill battle for yourself. JSX is huge time-saver and you should just learn how to work with it. Babel makes your life simple.

Comment: Thank you. I know. But I want to save all the performance that I can. One way is to let go off the JSX-to-JS transformation.

Comment: You're not supposed to do JSX transformation in the browser. You're meant to do it as a build step of your application. Then distribute the "compiled" application to the client. Read the first warning at the top of [this page](http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/browser/).

Comment: Agreed. But I do not want to add another step in the process. Eventually my team will be used to JS code and leave no room for a miss as well. We might as well create something around this that can improve the way React code is being used in the project and make the team even more comfortable. I know there are some projects already available that does this.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following trick (mimicking the first example on the React homepage):

```
const __ = Object.assign(React.createElement, React.DOM);

var HelloMessage = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return __.div({}, 'Hello ', this.props.name);
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(__(HelloMessage, {name:"John"}), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Here are all four homepage examples:

- https://jsfiddle.net/b4aj6gL9/
- https://jsfiddle.net/fd38ya0r/
- https://jsfiddle.net/f4uqqrjv/
- https://jsfiddle.net/905tL9k6/

While this code does use an unfamiliar idiom, the `__.` prefix offers a strong visual mnemonic that is just as readable as JSX. I'd say more readable, thanks to the absence of close tags.

Comment: In React v18 from production CDN the `React.DOM` appears to be undefined... It appears  that people are using built-in html elements with `React.createElement("div", ...)` rather than `React.DOM.div(...)`

Answer (score 1):

[NoJSX](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-nojsx) is a lightweight JSON based alternative. You can create a tree like the below...

```
- div.container.container--app
    -- div.jumbotron
        --- h1
        --- p
```

... by defining the tree structure of elements represented with properties including `children`, `props` and `type`. These mirror the arguments for [`React.createElement`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#createelement).

```
const pageHeader = {
  children: [
    {
      children: 'Hello World.',
      type: 'h1'
    },
    {
      children: 'Foobar.',
      type: 'p'
    }
  ],
  props: { className: 'jumbotron' },
  type: 'div'
};

const templateData = {
  children: [
    {
      props: { title },
      type: Helmet
    },
    pageHeader
  ],
  props: { className: 'container container--app' },
  type: 'div'
};

const template = new NoJSX(templateData);
return template.compile();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my preferred approach: https://github.com/simonrelet/react-pure-html-component-loader

This component is supposed to let you write pure html templates to use as components in react without mixing HTML with javascript in such a horrible way.

I see the repository has not been updated for a year, so this guy needs help if we want to be able to use react without that horrible JSX mixed inside the scripts.

Answer (score 1):

**Official documentations**

[Here is](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html) an official documentation how to use React without JSX.

Beside the mentioned alternative libraries to JSX,

I can suggest [React on lambda](https://github.com/sultan99/react-on-lambda) which makes coding on react in more functional way.

Comment: The official documentation now redirects to legacy.reactjs.org, I wonder if that means that using React without JSX is now officially deprecated...

Comment: You're right, the link redirects to the deprecated docs, but it doesn't mean that the usage is deprecated. JSX is not a part of the React library; it is also used by many other libraries like Solid and Astra. So, after transpiling, JSX tags are replaced by corresponding tag create functions. If you're interested in jsx-pragma, you can check this link: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/jsx-pragma-ucfxd

Comment: Yeah, my earlier assumption is probably wrong: after a bit of googling I did find the non-legacy official [documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react/createElement) on using React without JSX

Answer (score 0):

HyperScript Helpers are a JavaScript based option.

Less verbose than createElement and often JSX, but still plain JavaScript, so for example JavaScript comments, arrays, objects and functions are used,

JSX:

```
<MyComponent className='className'>Hi</MyComponent>
```

versus HyperScript Helpers:

```
MyComponent('.className', ['Hi'])
```

Example [HTML to HyperScript converter](http://html-to-hyperscript.paqmind.com/).

**Usage** from [React HyperScript Helpers library](https://github.com/jador/react-hyperscript-helpers):

DOM components are really easy to use. Just import and go.

```
import { div, h2 } from 'react-hyperscript-helpers';

export default () => div('.foo', [ h2('Hello, world') ]);
```

For custom components you can either create a factory function or use the h function, similar to react-hyperscript.

```
//MyComponent
import { div, hh } from 'react-hyperscript-helpers';

export default hh(() => div('Nifty Component'));

//Container
import MyComponent        from './MyComponent';
import SomeOtherComponent from 'who-whats-its';
import { div, h }         from  'react-hyperscript-helpers';

export default () => div('.foo', [
  MyComponent(),
  h(SomeOtherComponent, { foo: 'bar' })
]);
```